# Where is the MySQL query cache file saved?

Tags: mysql, file, query-cache

I'd like to see a dump of my MySQL query cache file, but can't seem to figure out where it's stored. I'm on a Windows machine -- which doesn't make it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just went through the documentation and a few searches but there doesn't seem to be a file for the query cache.

[The query cache operates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-operation.html) by storing the data in memory (though it doesn't specify how exactly) though from the looks of it, with the constraint of *"Queries must be exactly the same (byte for byte) to be seen as identical"* it is likely that it is hashing the query.

You can [view some information](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-status-and-maintenance.html) regarding the status of the query cache including free memory and hits on the cache, these are done with the SQL query `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Qcache%';`. I haven't yet seen a command to allow full viewing of the cache though I am not sure it is possible (or useful) if they are hashing the queries. [This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4188508/1676444) also mentions regarding the possibility of hashing and not being able to view the data stored.

I'm going to take a guess by wanting to view the query cache you may also want to [modify it's configuration](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache-configuration.html). You can modify the cache size which may impact the overall performance of your queries for better or worse. Personally, I have never modified it and unless you are running some extremely large site, you might not need to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't see anything in the documentation either. I'd like to view the file so I can see what queries are actually coming in from one of my websites. Seems like that won't be possible. I'll upvote you and accept in a bit if no one else has a solution.

Comment: I do see the want for such a feature though you may be better off with some layer in between your website code and the database which could do this type of debugging/logging for you. Obviously this isn't always possible given that it can require a lot of re-engineering of code but, that's the only other way off the top of my head.

Comment: Yeah, that makes more sense. In fact, just got confirmation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187794/how-to-list-cached-queries-in-mysql-qcache-queries-in-cache?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, query cache is stored in memory, not in file.