# Log queries which are cached and those which are not

Tags: php, mysql, caching

I am using PHP with MySQL 5.6 for my project and I wanted to test and log which of my queries are cached and which are not.

I am aware of the fact that if the same query is sent repeatedly to the DB again and again, it retrieves result from cache instead of fetching from DB. Now, thats what I want to check cause I want to optimize my queries.

Now how do I log this? Is there any way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're most interested in which queries are not cached, which are the ones really slowing things down. You might want to make use of the MySQL slow query log to spot them and use EXPLAIN to optimize each one individually.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/slow-query-log.html

However this answer is a "These are not the droids you're looking for" Jedi trick : it doesn't directly answer your question however but puts you on the right track. As far as I know, the MySQL query cache, like most caching layers, stores results through a hash-based key, making direct query-hash association rather painful : [How to list cached queries in MySQL? (Qcache_queries_in_cache)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187794/how-to-list-cached-queries-in-mysql-qcache-queries-in-cache)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the links. The SO link referred points out the number of cached queries but not the queries themselves.. 

Actually I am not worried about slow query log cause it has queries stored taking exec time above threshold value. I am just worried about caching of queries so that I can optimize the uncached queries and change them so that they are fast enough.

Comment: It is also possible actually make use of the slow query log to log each and every query processed, allowing you to browse them all as a whole and determine which ones are similar enough to be updated to make use of caching. That's how I would go about it.